# Magento payment bridge with CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST

Tags: php, magento, curl

We are using Magento enterprise edition 1.14.1.0. Payment bridge is not working with SSL.

When we ran below `curl` command, it worked fine

> curl -v --cipher rsa_rc4_128_sha --data ""

https://www.example.com/MagentoPaymentBridge1.11.31.0/pub/bridge.php?merchant_code=test

But the normal curl function throws error;

> curl -v --data ""

https://www.example.com/MagentoPaymentBridge1.11.31.0/pub/bridge.php?merchant_code=test

So I assume we need to edit payment bridge code something like below;

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'rsa_rc4_128_sha');

Please let us know which files and code I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit app/code/local/Enterprise/Pbridge/Model/Pbridge/Api/Abstract.php and added code as below for temporary fix;
 protected function _call(array $request)
    {
        $response = null;
        $debugData = array('request' => $request);
        try {
            $http = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
            $config = array('timeout' => 60);
            $http->setConfig($config);
            $http->addOption(CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'rsa_rc4_128_sha');
            $http->write(

Comment: I am facing problem with change db pass. Please have a look into it .
http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/136433/28515